# How can I stop a label from automatically trimming white spaces after a string?

Tags: javascript, temenos-quantum

In Kony Studio 6.5 I have a label in a form. In this label I have an i18n localized string. For formatting purposes, I want to add a space after the string. So far I've tried placing a space after the i18n key itself to no avail. I have also tried setting the label text in the form preShow() like so:

```
frmExample.lblSample.text = kony.i18n.getLocalizedString("my_i18n_key") + ' ';
```

I have also tried using unicode spaces and non-breaking spaces in the above code snippet, but all to no avail. Is there any way I can stop the label from automatically removing the trailing whitespaces?

Comment: You need to use the CSS white-space property : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp with "pre" or "pre-wrap". That prevents the collapsing of white spaces.

Comment: I'm not able to use CSS formatting for the native label skins in Kony.

Comment: The white-space is a css property, you either have to overrite the given CSS class or add the style afterwards with Javascript to your label.

Answer (score 3):

use `\xa0` in a string it is the character representing the HTML entity `&nbsp;` it won't get trimmed.